# python DLL load failed (statsmodels)

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

My Python version is 2.7.9 and OS is Windows 8.

Writing `import statsmodels.api`

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import statsmodels.api
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels-0.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\statsmodels\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .tools.sm_exceptions import (ConvergenceWarning, CacheWriteWarning,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels-0.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\statsmodels\tools\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tools import add_constant, categorical
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels-0.6.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\statsmodels\tools\tools.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import svdvals
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import blas
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

How can I solve this problem? I find `fblas.py  fblas.pyc _fblas.pyd` but no `_fblas.py`in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg`   Is this where the problem is?

Comment: do you have `scipy` installed?

Comment: yes I use pip install scipy and I checked it before I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there can be issues with certain scipy modules and pyinstaller. Modules such as linalg and interpolate rely on fblas.py which may be missing in the PythonVersion\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg folder.

This is an issue with numpy. Installing numpy+mkl fixed this for me and copied the correct file to this directory.

Numpy+mkl can be found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) Be sure to uninstall previous version of numpy.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have solved this problem before just like what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Download the scipy module (whl file) from this link whatever suits your configuration
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)

Then install scipy on python using
pip install scipy-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

This worked for me